# Swing Layout issue - JTable and JTree

Tags: java, swing

I am having trouble in using the layout in swing properly.

I am trying to achieve something like screenshot1 however I am getting something like screenshot2.

Please see my source code below.

What am I dong wrong? How can I achieve what I want (as in screenshot1).

**Note:** When I run the code multiple times, sometimes I get the alignment between table an tree getting correct. looks like a race condition here.

Screenshot1

[image: Screenshot1]

Screenshot2
[image: Screenshot2]

Source code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Date;

public class SwingLayoutTest {
    private static final int screenWidth;
    private static final int screenHeight;

    static {
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        screenWidth = screenSize.width;
        screenHeight = screenSize.height;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame();
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainWindow.setSize(800, 600);
        mainWindow.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        Container contentPane = mainWindow.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        JTree tree = createTree();
        tree.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth/2, screenHeight));
        JScrollPane scrollTree = new JScrollPane(tree);
        JTable table = createTable();
        table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth/2, screenHeight));
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setWidth(100);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setWidth(100);
        JScrollPane scrollTable = new JScrollPane(table);
        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, scrollTree, scrollTable);
        contentPane.add(splitPane);
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);

    }

    private static JTree createTree(){
        DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("This is root Node");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode child1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child 1");
        rootNode.add(child1);
        child1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child 1 1"));
        child1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child 1 2"));
        DefaultMutableTreeNode child2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child 2");
        rootNode.add(child2);
        child2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child 2 1"));
        child2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child 2 2"));
        return new JTree(rootNode);
    }

    private static JTable createTable(){
        String[] columnNames = {"Name", "Size", "Modified Time"};
        Object[][] data = {{"This is row 1","1000", new Date()},
                {"This is row 2", "5455", new Date()}};
        return new JTable(data, columnNames);
    }
}
```

Comment: One recommendation after a quick glance: don't use `setSize()` and don't forget to call `pack()`. In fact, do that now -- get rid of `setSize()` and let us know what happens.

Comment: Avoid using `setPreferredSize`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I tried removing mainWindow.setSize(). No luck, Same results!

Comment: @MadProgrammer, When I remove setPreferredSize(), the border between tree and table is close to the tree (tree is shrunk to it's content).

Comment: Although not recommended , this would work--Add this line `scrollTree.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth/2, screenHeight));` after you create `JScrollPane` containing the `tree`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html#divider):

> To make your split pane work well, you often need to set the minimum
>   sizes of components in the split pane, as well as the preferred size
>   of either the split pane or its contained components. Choosing which
>   sizes you should set is an art that requires understanding how a split
>   pane's preferred size and divider location are determined.

Why are you setting the size of the window to something small, then setting the size of the components to be the size of the screen? If you want that much to be visible, why not also set the size of your window to be the size of the screen?

Try calling `setDividerLocation` and/or `setResizeWeight` and messing with the minimum sizes of the table/tree components. There is no single correct answer here.

Comment: Thank you very much! setSize(screenWidth, screenHeight) and using setDividerLocation, solved location of table-tree boundary. I have more issue in this. The table column width, is equally divided, I want the last two columns fixed width (say 100 pixel) and first one take the remaining one (see code), it is not honoured. any clue?

Comment: You should be using `pack()` as @HovercraftFullOfEels already commented.  This would allow you to simply specify the preferred size of the left-hand component (the JTree) to be half the window width.  This allows the SplitPane divider to honor the component sizes correctly rather than using `setDividerLocation`, which will not necessarily work if there are other sizing or layout restrictions.  For your table widths, use `setMaxWidth(100)` instead of `setWidth(100)`.